# Windows 2008 R2 Backup to DVD

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, backup-restoration, optical-media

Been playing with Windows 2008 R2 and I ended up creating a backup of my test server and stored the backup files on my local machine. How can I copy the backup files from my local machine to a DVD? Also, would I be capable of using the backup files (assuming I can put them in a DVD) as a method of booting to a server regardless of if the image has an OS or not?

I'm a little confused right now so if anyone could help me figure out what I can do with backups I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

EDIT: For those curious, this has been what I've been using to do my searching:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755163.aspx

From the looks of it, it's possible to restore from a backup with a Windows Setup Disc, however I'm curious if there's a way to do it without needing one and using just the backup alone.

Comment: What software are you using to create your backup? And I don't believe you can use a backup of your server as a livecd with windows.  You can with Linux.

Comment: It would be possible to hack together a BMR solution using WinAIK and the Backup file you've created, but it would not be simple or elegant. DVDs aren't very convenient and are very sensitive to the environment (like being left in sunlight). A USB hard drive would make a much better backup storage option.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the built-in Windows Server Backup utility, you'll need to follow the steps outlined in the link that you posted.

You can make BMR (Bare Metal Restore) disks with other software like Symantec Netbackup, but if you're using the free Windows utility, you'll need a Windows setups disks to initiate a supported bare metal restore.

Comment: How difficult would it be to create the BMR disk with Symantec Netbackup? I looked on their website and it doesn't state anything about how to use the software (which I assume could be due to not owning it)